# iOS How to download image from parse in table view cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I work with one project, and i need to show images in table view cell's, which i have in parse data base.
My code to load text:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! cellRequestsTVC
    let good = data[indexPath.row]
    name = good["username"] as! String
    cell.userNameLable.text = "Name: \(name)"
    area = good["place"] as! String
    cell.areaLable.text = "Area: \(area)"
    cell.descriptionLable.text = good["description"] as? String
    cell.priorityLable.setRoundEdge()
cell.dataLable.text = good["openData"] as! String

    return cell
}
```

And i have one variable:

```
var data = [PFObject]()
```

How i can load image in cell, used parse?

Comment: do you have the imageURL in `PFObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAt` method get `PFFile` data in background like this.

```
let avatar = good["image"] as! PFFile
    avatar.getDataInBackground{ (imageData, error)in
        if imageData != nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.Image.image = image
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```